# RichTextBox to Text File Wont Save LineBreaks

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have a `RichTextBox` and a `Button` that saves its text to a .txt file.

However it does not save the LineBreaks `\n`. It ends up all in one line.

What could be preventing it? I'm using `Encoding.Unicode`.

**XAML**

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="rtbMessage" Margin="10,10,10,50" />

<Button x:Name="btnSave" Content="Save" Margin="231,264,211,29" Width="75" Click="btnSave_Click"/>
```

**C#**

```
String message = "Hello, world.\n\n This is a test.";
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();


// Startup
// Write Message to RichTextBox
//
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    rtbMessage.Document = new FlowDocument(p);

    rtbMessage.BeginChange();
        p.Inlines.Add(new Run(message));
    rtbMessage.EndChange();
}


// Copy RichTextBox to String
//
public String MessageRichTextBox()
{
    FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument(p);
    rtbMessage.Document = fd;

    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(
        rtbMessage.Document.ContentStart,
        rtbMessage.Document.ContentEnd
    );

    return textRange.Text;
}


// Save Message to .txt File
//
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog saveFile = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();

    // Save File Default Path same as Input Directory
    saveFile.RestoreDirectory = true;
    saveFile.Filter = "Text file (*.txt)|*.txt";
    saveFile.DefaultExt = ".txt";
    saveFile.FileName = "Message";

    // Show Save File dialog box
    Nullable<bool> result = saveFile.ShowDialog();

    // Process dialog box
    if (result == true)
    {
        // Save document
        File.WriteAllText(saveFile.FileName, MessageRichTextBox(), Encoding.Unicode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you view the saved file with Notepad? Your line breaks are `\n` and Notepad is not good at unix line endings. If you open the file with Notepad++, you will see the line breaks. Alternatively replace `\n` with `\r\n\r\n` in your text.

Comment: @YusufTarıkGünaydın I adjusted my code, the `\r\n` worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use richtextbox, but I use Environment.NewLine instead of "\n".

In your example:

```
String message = "Hello, world." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "This is a test.";
```

Maybe that is a workaround.

Comment: I tried `Environment.NewLine` but it still did not save.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are resetting the message when you grab it

```
public String MessageRichTextBox()
{
    FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument(p);
    rtbMessage.Document = fd;
```

Seems unnecessary and might the cause. I cant validate without a windows machine next to me (sorry on a Mac right now), just give it a try though

Comment: I removed that part, but it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 TextRange textRange = new TextRange(
        rtbMessage.Document.ContentStart,
        rtbMessage.Document.ContentEnd);
```

To

```
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(
            p.ContentStart,
            p.ContentEnd)
```

Comment: It gives the same result. It seems it's a Notepad problem. The linebreaks show in Sublime Text.

Comment: p.Inlines.Add(new Run(message)); what this statement does? As far as I know it does not add new line . correct me if I am wrong

Comment: That writes the `String message` which contains `Hello, world. \n\n This is a test.` The `\n` are the linebreaks.

Comment: It could also be `p.Inlines.Add(new Run("Hello, world. \n\n This is a test."));`

Comment: Environment.NewLine may work check while adding text

Comment: LineBreaks now working in Notepad using `\r\n` instead of `\n`. `"\r" + Environment.NewLine` also works.

Comment: That was issue finally \r\n